# Searching dataset for Constellation detection

Tags: photography, constellations, sky-survey, image-processing

I need to develop an Machine Learning (ML) model for predicting constellation seen in a picture taken from a mobile. This I need to develop from scratch. Firstly, I need help finding a database which can provide me **images of stars with constellations labelled** in it. Those can be from a ground based telescope or from a camera. This is going to be a multi-labelled problem. Even after spending hours of searching I can't find a good dataset. I want a dataset with several images (preferably a few 100), each labelled with the constellation seen in them. Then I am planning to refine them and use TensorFlow for prediction. I am a grade 12 student and still new to ML, so I really need your help.

Answer (score 1):

If actual photographs are not required, [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) could render a suitable set of reference images.
Use the Perspective ([gnomonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)) projection for the closest match to a photograph, and display only the features you want.
Its scripting capability may help you avoid repeating some manual operations.

Here are a sample pair of Stellarium images.
The first has only synthetic stars, which the online plate-solving service Astrometry.net successfully [recognizes](http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/3903926#annotated):

[image: 18h+0, stars only]

The second is the same part of the sky with only constellation labels and boundaries:

[image: 18h+0, constellations]

The unlabeled region between Ophiuchus and Scutum is [Serpens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpens) Cauda,
part of the only discontinuous one of the 88 standard [constellations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_designated_constellations).

Comment: This could be a good method but can you tell how can I render good enough resolution pictures from Stellarium especially if pictures are needed in bulk

Comment: @HarshBanka you haven't really explained what "good enough resolution" means. **brightness:** Do you need deep sky survey images that can see way farther and dimmer than humans and cellphones, or only images that reflect what people and hand-held cameras are likely to pick up? **resolution:** Do you need super high resolution images through telescopes, or only images of similar angular resolution to what people and hand-held cameras can achieve? Is it possible to clarify those things back in your original question, rather than in comments only? Thanks!