# Where can I find thousands of actual images of stars in the galaxy?

Tags: star, image-processing

I'm trying to write a program to differentiate between images of stars and nebulae. However, I'm not able to find a large enough dataset of actual images of stars that I can use to train my deep learning algorithm. Is there any database that has thousands of actual images of stars that I can use to train my deep learning algorithm? Thanks.

EDIT: I need individual images of stars so that my program can learn the identifying features of a star and be able to differentiate a star from another celestial object.

Comment: https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching dataset for Constellation detection](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38483/searching-dataset-for-constellation-detection)

Comment: The answer to that question is specifically about recognizing constellations, not about differentiating between stars and nebula, so I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: not a duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

The online version of the digitised sky survey will give you as many images of the sky as you want. Be aware that these are based on photographic plates. Also be aware that every imaging system has its own peculiarities in terms of the shape of the point spread function (i.e. the shape of a star in the image) and features such as diffraction spikes.

https://archive.eso.org/dss/dss

Comment: That link helped a lot, thank you! But is there one location I can go to where I can download all these images of stars? Because the link you've given requires me to screenshot each star individually, which will take lots of time. So is there one location where I can download a lot of individual images of stars? Again, thank you all so much for your help.